# Problem with "ps" command on Raspbian

Tags: linux

I've got an issue with the code fragment below:

```
#!/bin/bash
GREEN="\033[01;32m"
RESTORE="\033[0m" 
VALTIME=$(date '+%F %T')
PROCID=$(pgrep -u root *procname*)
RUNTIME=$(ps -p $PROCID -o,etime=) **<=== This is the problem line**
```

I had it working on the command line but somehow stuffed it up putting it into my shell script. I get the following error on a Raspberry Pi Model B running the December 2016 version of Raspbian Lite:

```
$  ps [options]
error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Can anyone point out the error for me? I think I've tried every combination of quotes "'", ticks "`", double quotes '"' imaginable but just can't get past this error. I suspect the '-p' option is the culprit.

I'm trying to get the process run time in hh:mm:ss to display on the console as part of a housekeeping script for my CumulusMX weather station.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't figure out the enter/newline issue.

Comment: you have a stray comma in `-o,etime`

Answer (score 1):

For me I get `improper format list`. I believe this is what you are looking for, although you will have to trim `$RUNTIME`:

```
#!/bin/bash
GREEN="\033[01;32m"
RESTORE="\033[0m"
VALTIME=$(date '+%F %T')
PROCID=$(pgrep -u root dhcpcd)
RUNTIME=$(ps -p $PROCID -o etime=)
```

`echo`ing `$RUNTIME` gives something like this:

```
    ELAPSED
      26:50
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please upvote and accept it.